# (Jquery) On click div expands with css transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, expand

I want to expand and decrease height of header when I press click on div "arrow". I've tried to addClass with Jquery, but it doesn't really work
HTML:

```
<header>
    <p>The title..</p>
    <h1>Some text</h1>
      <div class="arrow" id="arrow">
        <img src="img/arrow.svg" />
      </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header { 
  background: #2282A4;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  transition: height 0.5 ease;
}
expandheight {
  height: 850px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
      $('#arrow').click(function() {
         $('header').addClass('expandheight');
}); 
}); 
});
```

I don't know how I can decrease height now with the same button, to remove "expandheight" class when it is active and add it when it is not... I've tried if/else, I failed.

Comment: add 'px'  to your css class

Comment: I've written wrong here, in my code I specified 850px......

Comment: Please add . (dot) before class (css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors:

1. `expandheight` should be styled using `.expandheight`
2. use cross browser animation properties
3. use `toggleClass` to add/remove class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#arrow').click(function() {
      $('header').toggleClass('expandheight');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  background: #2282A4;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;      
  -webkit-transition:height 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition:height 0.5s ease;
  transition:height 0.5s ease;
}

.expandheight {
  height: 850px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <p>The title..</p>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <div class="arrow" id="arrow">
     <img src="img/arrow.svg" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I know, I was in a hurry when I wrote here. I wanna know how to remove "expandheight" class when I press again on "arrow"...

Comment: Lol, I didn't tried to use toggle, because I didn't know how I can use that. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand and decrease the height of the header, use toggleClass() rather than using addClass()

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#arrow').click(function() {
            jQuery('header').toggleClass('expandheight');
        });
    });
});
```

Also, you had a few errors in your code. I have created a jsfiddle to show you it working.

https://jsfiddle.net/7yodz723/

(I put a border around the arrow just so we can clearly see the example working)

Answer (score 0):

Just use toggle class to switch classes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#arrow').click(function() {
      $('header').toggleClass('expandheight');
  });
 });
});
```

```css
header { 
  background: #2282A4;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  transition: height 0.5 ease;
}
.expandheight {
  height: 850px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <p>The title..</p>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <div class="arrow" id="arrow">
     <img src="img/arrow.svg" />
  </div>
</header>
```